# Rewriting WACC Formula

Tags: finance, wacc

$WACC = \frac{E}{V} * R_e + \frac{D}{V} *R_D(1-T_c) $

where $R_D$ should be the cost of the debt. $T_c$ is the tax rate.
When googling the formula for cost of debt I find $Cost of debt = R_D = Interest*(1-tax rate)$

But this looks identical to the $R_D(1-T_c$) part, if only $R_d$ was interest rate in the WACC Formula. Does this mean we can rewrite WACC to

$WACC = \frac{E}{V}*R_e +\frac{D}{V}*r_i*(1-T_c)^2$ where $r_i$ is the interest rate, or is there something I'm not understanding correctly here?

Comment: No, there is no squared term.  It is just a notation difference.

Comment: What you call "Costofdebt" is the "After Tax Cost of Debt". It is already included in the WACC formula as $R_D(1-T_c)$

Comment: I see, thank you